# "unable to switch the encoding" error when "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no" ?>" at XML beginning

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing

While shredding the XML in SQL this way:

```
DECLARE @XML2 XML
SET @XML2 = '
<App_MemberServers>
<memberServers>
<client _type_="3" clientId="3" clientName="TokyoProxy" clientSidePackage="1" consumeLicense="1" srmReportSet="0" srmReportType="0" type="0"/>
</memberServers>
</App_MemberServers>'

select a.b.value('@clientId','INT') ClientID
from @XML2.nodes('/App_MemberServers/memberServers/client') a(b)
```

It works fine, but when the XML is

```
DECLARE @XML2 XML
SET @XML2 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no" ?>
<App_MemberServers>
<memberServers>
<client _type_="3" clientId="3" clientName="TokyoProxy" clientSidePackage="1" consumeLicense="1" srmReportSet="0" srmReportType="0" type="0"/>
</memberServers>
</App_MemberServers>'

select a.b.value('@clientId','INT') ClientID
from @XML2.nodes('/App_MemberServers/memberServers/client') a(b)
```

I get the following issue "unable to switch the encoding"

Why? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because your string is not in utf-16. add `N` before string literal to make it UTF:

```
DECLARE @XML2 XML
SET @XML2 = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no" ?>
<App_MemberServers>
<memberServers>
<client _type_="3" clientId="3" clientName="TokyoProxy" clientSidePackage="1" consumeLicense="1" srmReportSet="0" srmReportType="0" type="0"/>
</memberServers>
</App_MemberServers>'

select a.b.value('@clientId','INT') ClientID
from @XML2.nodes('/App_MemberServers/memberServers/client') a(b)
```